How to Extract Keys from a Loop in Scriban?
I'm trying to extract the keys from a loop in Scriban, but I couldn't find a way to do this in the documentation: Scriban language.md(https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/language.md#95-loops)
Here's how I call the Scriban render function in my code:
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonStr);
var scriptObject = new ScriptObject();
scriptObject.Import(new { data = jsonObj });
var context = new TemplateContext();
context.PushGlobal(scriptObject);
string html = parsedTemplate.Render(context);

My Scriban template looks like this:
{{for summary in data.Summary}}
    {{for iter in summary}}
        (File Count: {{ iter.FileNum }})
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}

And the JSON data looks like this:
{
  "Summary": {
    "Added": {
      "FileNum": 10
        },
        "Removed": {
      "FileNum": 2
        },
        "Updated": {
      "FileNum": 3
        },      
}

I want to display the keys Added, Removed, and Updated alongside their corresponding values. Ideally, I would like to use a construct like {{for key, value in summary}}, but I couldn't find any syntax for this in Scriban.
How can I access the keys of a loop in Scriban?
